# To receive payments from a US company, do you need to start a LLC/PVT in India?

Tags: india, limited-liability-company, self-employment, salary

A person, let's say "X" got an offer from a US company as a Consultant. X lives in India. **To receive payments from US company, does X need to start a LLC/PVT in India?**

How can X receive payments for the consulting services provided to the US company?

Answer (score 1):

> How can X receive payments for the consulant services provided for US company ?

the company Send Money to X.

> does X need to start a LLC/PVT in India?

No, there would be perhaps ***hundreds of thousands*** of people in India who get paid as individuals (simply "self-employed" in India) for freelancing from the US. I just paid like three! I have rarely, indeed, never, seen a freelance programmer in India bother with company formation.

Comment: Thanks @Fattie for your reply. Ofcouse the company will send money to X. From the tax point of view , which one is better ? Receive funds via company ? OR Receive funds directly in X's account? Thanks much.

Comment: Please note that your question, both the title and body, ask whether you NEED to start a llc/pvt.   You do not need to.  Regarding which is *better* tax wise in India, you'd need to ask a new question, and the answer would be very complicated and depend on the exact amounts. etc.  As I mention in the answer, I have rarely, indeed, never, seen a freelance programmer in India bother with company formation.